# C++ store number in char using int variable

Tags: c++, char, int

I need to be able to store number in char using variable and later able to detect if it is number or character for print, will try to explain with below's code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> vChar;
    int testInt = 67;
    char testChar = 'x';
    char printChar;

    vChar.push_back(testInt);
    vChar.push_back(testChar);

    while (!vChar.empty()) {
        printChar = vChar.back();
        vChar.pop_back();
        cout << printChar << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above code will output "x C", which is incorrect, because "cout" is printing "printChar" as char not as int and 67 is C in ASCII.

I could cast "int" over "printChar" but that would make it output "120 67", which is still incorrect. I have also tried to use conditions to detect which one is number, which one is character.

```
while (!vChar.empty()) {
    printChar = vChar.back();
    vChar.pop_back();
    if (isdigit(printChar)) {
        cout << int(printChar) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << printChar << endl;
    }
}
```

but "isdigit()" is never triggered and the result is same as without "int" cast...

How can I correctly print/output string for both numbers and characters using "char" type?

PS. I'm doing this for my school project to calculate matrixes, and using char for symbolicmatrixes is forced, thus I have to somehow be able to store both character and integer using char while differentiating them from each other.

Comment: Save the data as strings instead of `char`?

Comment: What if you want to store a number like 256, or 1000? Or did the academic that laid down the real-world-detached assignment restrictions already cover that with something you didn't mention here?

Comment: @WhozCraig to be honest with you I have no idea why would they restrict us like this... I have been fighting over this problem for few hours now without any clear idea how to solve it

Comment: So... back to my question, what is the upper limit on the magnitude of the "number" you're storing? I have reason for asking, but it is non-trivial to explain, and pointless to do so if the answer is unknown or outside a limited domain.

Comment: @WhozCraig safe to assume it will not out of char range so "-128 to 127"

Comment: Well therein lies you problem, if that really is the allowable domain for your "number" values. That covers the entire range of a signed 8-bit octet, which is also inclusive of your `char` domain. Without outside help (a different place to store data besides your vector-of-char) it simply isn't possible. If you had told me "numbers can be in 0..100 and chars will be regular ascii only" I would have suggested mapping your numbers on the *negative* side of the signed-char domain. But if it is as you put it, that's off the table, and so is pretty much everything else value-storage-wise.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see... Yes I have to be able to put negative numbers in it also so the range is as I said... 

Perhaps R Sahu suggested answer is the best one then? Converting my codes to accommodate his suggestion will be pain in ass, so I want to be sure before I continue...

Comment: I don't see another option if value-storage is the intent. If the full breadth of the signed-char domain -128...127 is viable for number storage, your only option is signifying char vs. number via something other than the value itself. R Sahu's method has the added benefit of working independent of system char signedness (some actually have unsigned char as `char`). Before you start on that endeavor, make sure you're crystal clear on the problem from your instructor (good luck with that, btw, it's probably more challenging getting useful time with them than this assignment seems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I correctly print/output string for both numbers and characters using "char" type?

One option is store the additional information.

Instead of using

```
vector<char> vChar;
```

use

```
// The first of the pair indicates whether the stored value
// is meant to be used as an int.
vector<std::pair<bool, char>> vChar;
```

and then

```
vChar.push_back({true, testInt});
vChar.push_back({false, testChar});

while (!vChar.empty()) {
    auto printChar = vChar.back();
    vChar.pop_back();
    if ( printChar.first )
    {
       cout << (int)(printChar.second) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
       cout << printChar.second << endl;
    }
}
```